Jitsi Meet Docker Compose Setup with Traefik: WSS Websocket-Error
I am using Traefik with entrypoints (a treafik docker container running) to route “sub.mydomain.com” (https://sub.mydomain.com/) to my jitsi running dockers.
The 4 jitsi standard docker containers are connected through “ports” entries in the docker-compose.yml, except the web container/service with “expose” instead of “ports” (since the traefik container has ports 80 and 443).
All container are in one network, created with the traefik container.
I am using the docker jitsi image version: stable-9457-2.
The Jitsi Meet welcome page is reachable. I cannot start a new session, it kicks me out at once. Through starting in Linux Terminal (docker compose -f jitsi-docker-compose.yml up -d), I got the following error visible in my Chrome browser development console on the other “testing access” machine:
<Pa.connectionHandler>:  (TIME) Strophe connecting:  3901.5999999996275
strophe.stream-management.js:224 WebSocket connection to 'wss://meet.mydomain.com/xmpp-websocket?room=test' failed: 
_connect @ strophe.umd.js:5779
...
connect @ xmpp.js:685
Bh.connect @ JitsiConnection.js:72
...
strophe.util.js:84 2024-05-12T19:27:04.287Z [modules/xmpp/strophe.util.js] <Pa.St.Strophe.log>:  Strophe: Websocket error {"isTrusted":true} Websocket error {"isTrusted":true}
...
socket.onerror @ strophe.umd.js:5783
error (async)
...
xmpp.js:292 2024-05-12T19:27:04.288Z [modules/xmpp/xmpp.js] <Pa.connectionHandler>:  (TIME) Strophe connfail[The WebSocket connection could not be established or was disconnected.]:    3934.800000000745
strophe.util.js:84 2024-05-12T19:27:04.288Z [modules/xmpp/strophe.util.js] <Pa.St.Strophe.log>:  Strophe: Websocket closed unexcectedly Websocket closed unexcectedly

There is a thread in this forum but I started one new, because I have another setup.
And my error seems related WSS websocket both, the xmpp websocket and the colibri websocket, the WSS connection primarily.
I would post my yml files, but before I would like to know if I should post them completely with all the config tries made and commnted out, or just the running config.
By the way, to which Jitsi component does the wss connection go? Web, Prosody. Jicofo or JVB?
Until now, I solved server errors existing beneath the broken wss connection. Most of them DNS or URL related. See at: https://community.jitsi.org/t/jitsi-meet-docker-compose-setup-with-traefik-dns-error/131556
I made the chrome browser error dissapear and the wss connection seems to go through.
Seems my hardware setup makes it hard for Jitsi to resolve DNS and/or URLs.
My Meet server runs behind a Fritz router and should be reachable in the local network and from the internet.
Running behind a NAT configs only didn't work. Since Jitsi runs as docker compose behind traefik as proxy.
I edited the hosts information on the test access machine (Windows, hosts file) and the server machine (Linux, resolv.conf.head file):
<Router IP in the router network>         meet.mydomain.com      #Jitsi Meet URL
<Router IP in the router network>         xmpp.meet.mydomain.com #Jitsi XMPP Meet URL

<Router IP in the router network>         muc.meet.mydomain.com 
<Router IP in the router network>         internal-muc.meet.mydomain.com

Network and Internet Traefik is routed through the router to the server by portforwarding in the router. Thus, using the router ip in the router network instead of the server ip in the router network.
Going back and forth I think I have pinned the Error.
The error "Websockets enabled, but no domains specified" didn't go away. It just appeared differently in the attached live log from docker.
What remains is that it is the "jisti-jvb" container, i.e. the video bridge, and the text portion is "Websockets enabled, but no domains specified".
In the browser the error is stated as "WebSocket connection to 'wss://meet.mydomain.comt/xmpp-websocket?room=test' failed ... Websocket closed unexcectedly".
Seems like the Traefik and Jitsi Meet combination isn't ready for use yet.
I return to Jitsi Meet with nginx in the Docker variant... or if that doesn't work either, I'll return to a standard, i.e. non-Docker, installation.

The error went away. But now just nothing happens when joining a room...
